# Unable to install platformio in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, platformio

Platfromio failed to install even with restart and changed rights on the .platformio folder, both in VSCode and Atom.

Comment: What fails exactly? Is there an error message? Even though you answered your own question, this is unlikely to be helpful to other users

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to

1. start the installation , when it fails, create a `.platformio` folder to the `C:`(OS drive)
2. Try installing again to populate this folder with content, but it most likely will fail again.
3. Open a commandline window in the `.platfromio` folder and run the following command:

`python3\python.exe .cache\tmp\get-platformio-0.3.5.py`

even if it fails, it will most likely install the platformio IDE for VSCode correctly.